# $(X,\tau)$ a topological space with $X\neq \emptyset$ and $D = \{D \subseteq X : D$ is dense in $(X, \tau) \}$.

Tags: general-topology

Be $(X,\tau)$ a topological space with $X\neq \emptyset$ and $D = \{D \subseteq
X : D$ is dense in $(X, \tau) \}$.

**(a)Prove that it is a discrete topology over X if, and only if, $D = \{X\}$.**

**Definition. The discrete topology is formed by the parts of X, i.e, ℘(X).**

From the imprint that only set X is dense in itself, and no other subset of $X$ is dense in $X$.

**(b) Prove that τ is the chaotic topology on X if, and only if, $D$ =
℘(X) - {∅}.**

**Definition. The caotica topology consists of: $\{\emptyset, X\}$**

Can you help me, please?

Comment: *Hints*: The closure, in $(X,\tau)$, of a subset $A$ of $X$ is a closed set in $(X,\tau)$ that contains $A$. In the discrete topology all the subsets of $X$ are closed. In the chaotic topology the only subsets of $X$ that are closed are $\varnothing$ and $X$.

Comment: $D=\{D\subseteq X:D\text{ is dense in }\langle X,\tau\rangle\}$ is impossible: you’re using $D$ both for the name of the set and as a dummy variable for the members of the set. I suspect that you mean $\mathscr{D}=\{D\subseteq X:D\text{ is dense in }\langle X,\tau\rangle\}$. Use `\mathscr{D}` to get $\mathscr{D}$ or `\mathcal{D}` to get $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: The usual English names for the topology $\{\varnothing,X\}$ are *indiscrete topology* and *trivial topology* on $X$.

Comment: Got it, you can help me, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

A subset $D$ of $X$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $\operatorname{cl}D=X$.

- Show that if $X$ has the discrete topology, $\operatorname{cl}A=A$ for every $A\subseteq X$.
- Show that if $X$ has the indiscrete topology, $\operatorname{cl}A=X$ for every non-empty $A\subseteq X$.

Once you’ve done this, you’ll have shown $X$ is the only dense subset of $X$ in the discrete topology, and every non-empty subset of $X$ is dense in $X$ in the indiscrete topology. (Why?)

For the other direction, you want to show (a) that if $X$ is the only dense subset of $X$, then $X$ has the discrete topology, and (b) that if every non-empty subset of $X$ is dense in $X$, then $X$ has the indiscrete topology.

- For (b), show that if every non-empty subset of $X$ is dense in $X$, then the only closed sets in $X$ are $\varnothing$ and $X$. HINT: If $F\subseteq X$ is closed, then $F=\operatorname{cl}F$.
- For (a), note that if $X$ does **not** have the discrete topology, then there is an $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is not open; show that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: Thank you so much again !!!!

Comment: @milou: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @milou, can you please accept the answers that have been useful to you? We see that you asked 17 questions without accepting any answer. This is definitely not polite and you should at least try to follow the rules of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Brian M. Scott Answer:
Claim: In (a) part, Converse part:
Suppose $D=\{X\}$ and Let there is some subset of $X$ not open in $X$ , let's say $\{x\}$
then,
Claiming $X\setminus\{x\}$ is dense in $X$ :
Then for every $U$ subset of $\tau$ such that
if $x \in U$ then $U\cap(X\setminus\{x\})$ not equal to $\phi$ as $\{x\}$ is not open in $\tau$.
So, clearly $X\setminus\{x\}$ is dense in $X$.